# Can you make torrents start downloading only AFTER the previous torrent has finished downloading in uTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

If I have multiple downloads I can have them all download simultaneously or pause one and let the other download and then when the 1st is done I manually pause it and have the second download, afterward I let both seed for a while. But How can I set it so that the 2nd torrent will start downloading only after the 1st has finished.

And is it possible to have the 1st pause seeding after it has finished downloading. I have nothing against seeding but I want to wait till all my downloads are done before sole seeding.

If these things aren't possible in uTorrent is there another client that handles these things?

Answer (score 13):

For your first question:

Options → Preferences → Queuing → Max. number of active downloads = 1

[image]

For the second one, under seeding goals, keep it as zero and if required, put a limit on the upload rate.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options>Preferences>Queuing

You can set it there.